# Registering a Widget Javascript Dependency on Sitefinity

Tags: javascript, sitefinity

I'm trying to see if there is a way like Wordpress's enqueue script to properly include scripts onto the footer.  I looked up the documentation, but all I could find was a way to do it for Widget Designers.  I am looking for the ways to include the script properly and I'm using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I dug this up from the forums: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/where-to-store-mvc-widget-css-and-javascript-and-how-to-link-it

You could also include the js reference in your master page, which I know isn't ideal if the widget isn't used on every page. You could always bundle and minify site wide scripts to reduce the overhead a bit.

You could also try using a the Sitefinity js widget on the page the widget is used, there is an option to refrence a file and include it before the closing body tag: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/user-guide/widgets/scripts-and-styles-widgets-group/configuring-the-java-script-widget